# Error of compiling the wrf-chem V3.5 model

Tags: wrf-chem

I have gone through the link (http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php) to build wrf libraries. I installed netcdf v4.1.3, mpich v3.0.4, jasper v1.900.1, zlib v1.2.7, and libpng v1.2.50 on the server. However, I could not compile my WRF-chem v3.5 and got some errors. I also could not generate the ndown.exe, nup.exe, real.exe, and wrf.exe.

The link is my compile log file: [compile.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/egyfmw7rlhe8wn0/compile.log?dl=0)

I was not sure if I missed any required libraries or did something wrong.

Would anyone please kindly give me some suggestions on this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,

Qianjin